# create binary encoded columns based on levels of data frame's factors meta data

Tags: r

I would like to create "binary encoding columns" of factor columns. There are various codes out there, which work fine for data frames with many rows (i.e. which have at least one row for each level). My use case is that I may only have the factors levels as "meta data" in the data frame.

So given a data frame like this:

```
haves <- data.frame(x = "a")
haves$x <- factor(as.character(haves$x), ordered = FALSE, levels = c(
        "a"
        , "b"
        , "c"
    ))
```

I would like to obtain this (based on 3 levels => ceiling(log2(3)) => 2 columns):

```
x bin_x_1 bin_x_2
a       0       0
```

I made an attempt below, which does not fully work.

```
library(binaryLogic)

encode_binary <- function(x, name = "binary_") {
    x2 <- as.binary(unique(unclass(x)) - 1)
    maxlen <- ceiling(log2(nlevels(x)))
    x2 <- lapply(x2, function(y) {
        l <- length(y)
        if (l < maxlen) {
            y <- c(rep(0, (maxlen - l)), y)
        }
        y
    })
    d <- as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(x2)))
    rownames(d) <- NULL
    colnames(d) <- paste0(name, 1:maxlen)
    d
}

haves <- data.frame(x = "a")
haves$x <- factor(as.character(haves$x), ordered = FALSE, levels = c(
        "a"
        , "b"
        , "c"
    ))

wants <- cbind(haves, encode_binary(haves[["x"]], name = "bin_x_"))
wants
```

PS:

ceiling(log2(n)) determines how many columns/bits are required to encode levels.

Comment: for 2 levels you need 1 column, for 3 + 4, 2 columns (i.e. bits). Does this make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `intToBits`:

```
t(sapply(unclass(haves$x)-1, function(x) as.integer(intToBits(x)))[
  seq_len(ceiling(log2(nlevels(haves$x)))),])
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    0
```

and as a function:

```
encode_binary <- function(x, name = "binary_") {
  x <- t(sapply(unclass(x)-1, function(x) as.integer(intToBits(x)))[
          seq_len(ceiling(log2(nlevels(x)))), , drop = FALSE])
  colnames(x) <- paste0(name, seq_len(ncol(x)))
  as.data.frame(x)
}
encode_binary(haves$x)
#     binary_1 binary_2
#[1,]        0        0
```

Comment: thanks. I tried using intToBits recently. could one adapt the code to work for several columns (I mean not having to use these 2 lines of code for every column - i.e having a function which takes the columns name and possibly start name for each resulting binary column)

Comment: I added a function.

Comment: for some reason this does not work. Test case: df <- data.frame(x1 = c("a", "b", "c"), x2 = c("a1", "a1", "c1"))
str(df)
t1 <- encode_binary(df$x1, "binary_x1_")
t2 <- encode_binary(df$x2, "binary_x2_")
t2 has 3 "columns" despite 2 levels. Could you please have a look also so that function returns dataframe? Thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry. I forgot a `drop = FALSE` during subseting. Also added `as.data.frame`. Hope it works now.